# Angular Send HTTP POST Request without Headers

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

I want to make Angular (I'm using 4.0.2 fwiw) send a very minimal HTTP POST request. By default, e.g. if I run code like this:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
export class MyService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http.post("http://some_url/", "{}");
  }  
}
```

I get a *lot* of HTTP Request headers sent by my application to some_url. I want to send the barest minimum, since the server in question actually cares *not at all* about the request headers for this application. As it stands I'm seeing all these headers, which is like 100x my payload size.

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
content-type:text/plain
Host:192.168.4.1
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:ed111a30-afdb-4b86-9717-d5f22a18d8e5
X-DevTools-Request-Id:20251.498
X-Requested-With:com.ionicframework.myapp123456
```

Comment: `content-type` is a required header for `post` calls

Comment: @Aravind I understand that it's necessary for a standards compliant server, but mine is a custom (embedded server). At any rate, I don't mind sending "the minimum" no need to make Angular bend over backwards, but I want to remove as much as possible.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: @aravind no sorry, haven't heard of it

Comment: send the `RequstOptionArgs` parameter explicitly with headers as undefined. clear??

Comment: @Aravind OK, I can give that a try, but I was digging around in the Angular src and it looked like they "merge" the RequestOptionArgs into defaultOptionArgs. I'll report back on what I find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144101/discussion-between-aravind-and-vicatcu).

Comment: I'm also trying to do that. I also tried Jquery post but I couldn't do. **Content-type** is added automatically. Postman does not set these headers automatically

Answer (score 0):

Your request is probably form encoded, so you should set headers: 
{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}